# Matplotlib: Italic style in regular font

Tags: python, matplotlib, text, fonts, italic

I am trying to write a text in the plot in italic. Although I want the style to be italic, I want to keep the font to be the regular font. This is what I did.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
plt.axis([0, 4, 0, 4])

# Add R^2, and P-value
ax.text(1, 2, 'Adj$\mathregular{\mathit{R}^2}$ = 0.5 ($\mathregular{\mathit{P}}$ = 0.03)', fontsize = 20)
# R^2 and P should be italic with regular font
plt.show()
```

[image]

This is what I get and the font seemed to have changed to Times Roman or something. How could I fix this? Thank you for any help.

Comment: Easiest solution: Update your matplotlib. The exact code from the question results in [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CD4S7.png) with newer versions of matplotlib.

Comment: For older versions, you probably need to read through the [Fonts section](https://matplotlib.org/1.5.3/users/mathtext.html#fonts) of the mathtext article.

Comment: Which version do you need to update it to? I just updated it but it still gave me the same figure I uploaded.

Comment: Version 2.0 or higher will produce the graph I've shown above.

Comment: It did the trick! The version I thought was the latest was not up to date. Thank you.